# OpenCV findContours in python

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am working in python on openCV 3.0. In order to find the largest white pixel region, first of all thresholded gray image to binary image.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('graimage.png') 

img = cv2.resize(img,(400,500))

gray = img.copy()

(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )

derp,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

But it shows error as follows.

> cv2.error: ..../opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:198: error: (-210) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function cvStartFindContours.

Comment: Is your image 8 bit Unsigned char? Or you can write 'img=imread('grainimage.png',0)' to convert into grayscale.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this was answered in the comments, but just to mark the question as answered:

CV_8UC1 means 8-bit pixels, unsigned, and only one channel, so grayscale. It looks like you're reading it in with 3 color channels, or CV_8UC3. You can check the image type by printing `img.dtype` and `img.shape`. The dtype should be uint8, and the shape should be (#, #), indicating two dimensions. I'm guessing you'll see that shape prints (#, #, 3) for your image as-is, indicating three color channels.

As @user3515225 said, you can fix that by reading the image in as grayscale using `cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`. That assumes you have no use for color anywhere else, though. If you want a separate grayscale *copy* of the image, then replace `gray = img.copy()` with `gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)` instead.