# Circle the segmented image to the original

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, scikit-image

I am new to Python.
I have read this ([How to overlay segmented image on top of main image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576686/how-to-overlay-segmented-image-on-top-of-main-image-in-python)) but unfortunately I cannot get to the desired result for the example provided below. The three following images are:

1. The main image.
2. The segmented image.
3. The result of overlaying and circling (which isn't working). The
   code is below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
os.chdir('/home/.../Desktop/python question')

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage import measure
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import cv2


# main image:
main = cv2.imread('main.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.imshow(main, cmap='gray')
#cv2.imshow("main", main)

# segmented image:
seg = cv2.imread('seg.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.imshow(seg, cmap='gray')
#cv2.imshow("seg", seg)

# Dictionary giving RGB colour for label (segment label) - label 1 in red, label 2 in yellow
RGBforLabel = {1:(0,0,255),
               2:(0,555,255)}


# Find external contours

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(main, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

from statistics import mean

# Iterate over all contours
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    # Find mean colour inside this contour by doing a masked mean
    mask = np.zeros(seg.shape[:2], np.uint8) # add [:2] after shape if bug
    #cv2.drawContours(mask,[c],-1,255, -1)
    cv2.drawContours(mask,[c], -1,(255,0,0), -1)
    # DEBUG: cv2.imwrite(f"mask-{i}.png",mask)
    mean,_, _, _ = cv2.mean(seg, mask=mask)
    # DEBUG: print(f"i: {i}, mean: {mean}")
    #print(f"i: {i}, mean: {mean}")


    # Get appropriate colour for this label
    label = 2 if mean > 1.0 else 1
    colour = RGBforLabel.get(label)
    # DEBUG: print(f"Colour: {colour}")

    # Outline contour in that colour on main image, line thickness=1
    #cv2.drawContours(main,[c],-1,colour,33)
    main2 = cv2.drawContours(main,[c],-1,(0, 255, 0),3)

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', main)
```

This doesn't produce the desired result. I want only the triangle to be circled all around its shape (whatever the colour, for example in red).

Please, can you point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're not converting the main image back into a color image, which I'd presume is what you need to do to overlay a colored outline on the perimeter of the triangle. In the answer you cited, they did so by re-defining the value of main after it was read in grayscale:

```
main = cv2.imread('main.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
main = cv2.cvtColor(main,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

You may need to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but I have the following error message: Cell In[5], line 1
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(main, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:195: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

Comment: In that case, the RETR_EXTERNAL contour retrieval mode that you specify when you read the contours might be where the problem is. You might try some of the [other options](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html). Also see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757273/opencv-findcontours-complains-if-used-with-black-white-image).

Comment: I tried with RETR_LIST, RETR_CCOMP, RETR_TREE but none work. Error = error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:195: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'.

Comment: I also tried to add seg = np.uint8(seg) and the same for the main image, but it doesn't work. error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:195: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

Comment: I was mistaken. However, you're running `findContours` against the `main` image, rather than the segmented one, which is why you're getting that error after converting `main` back to color; [findContours expects grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713502/470477). As such, you should either convert `main` back to color _after_ you've found the contours, or use `seg` in the `findContours` call, as in the example you linked to.